# VS Code and TypeScript - getting "tl-node is not recognized"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code, and I am having a hard time determining how to get VSCODE to compile TS code.

Some sources out there says that VSCODE comes with a "stable" version of TS, others talk about installing TS. In either case, when I write this simple code in a sample.ts file:

```
// sample.ts

function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}

console.log(add(2,2)); // 4
```

then I get this error:

> [Running] ts-node
>   "i:\UserData\Ted\Documents\typescript-test\sample.ts" 'ts-node' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

What can I do to fix this? Does VS Code have TS installed so it can "compile" and run? If so, what am I doing from or missing, if not, how do I fix?

I have used npm to install TypeScript might I add (so I have it in C:\Users\Ted\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript).

Comment: The error saying you are trying to use `ts-node` and it is not installed. How are you "running/compiling" your file? Installing `ts-node` may fix the problem, but it is better to first understand why are you running with `ts-node` in the first place.

Comment: For a pretty full-fledged example that does not use `ts-node`, you can look at one of my package, e.g. https://github.com/unional/color-map

Comment: Or a smaller example: https://github.com/blakeembrey/hasvalue

Comment: Well, I just installed VS COde and then to run it, I go "CTRL + ALT + N".

Comment: So, Im sort of asking if 1) VS Code comes with TypeScript support, to compile and stuff, and 2) If not, and I have TS installed, what next? =)

Comment: Never try that before. Interesting. It does use the global `ts-node` for that purpose. You can file an issue at vscode repo, this should be taken care of by the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you described does require a global `ts-node` to be installed.

You should file in issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues about this.

The installer should take care of this.

However, I think it is still experimental because there are some obvious bugs.

For example, if you use any external packages, this feature will not work because this feature did not load and resolve those dependencies.

Again, filling an issue on that would be wonderful. :)

And thanks for pointing it out. I didn't know this feature exist before. :)